# Retrieving TrailerFields from HttpServletResponse in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

`Service A` contacts another `Service B` which returns servlet response with trailer fields added as part of the response in HttpServletResponse. `Service B` uses Jersey for REST. `Service A` runs Spring Boot.

I am trying to retrieve the Trailer Fields in the HttpServletResponse.

I was using RestTemplate `exchange` to send the request and return the response to the client calling Service A with ResponseEntity. I tried using `postHandle` to retrieve the fields. But then I came across the following:

> the postHandle method of HandlerInterceptor is not always ideally
> suited for use with @ResponseBody and ResponseEntity methods. In such
> cases an HttpMessageConverter writes to and commits the response
> before postHandle is called which makes it impossible to change the
> response, for example to add a header. Instead an application can
> implement ResponseBodyAdvice and either declare it as an
> @ControllerAdvice bean or configure it directly on
> RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.

Now I use Apache HttpClient to send and retrieve the response. I still find that the Trailer Fields are null both in the interceptor and in the controller method with HttpServletResponse as a parameter.

I also implemented the ResponseBodyAdvice and still find the response missing the trailer fields.

Is there a way to retrieve the Trailer Fields that are set by Service B? If I run a `curl --raw` request to Service B, I am able to see the trailer fields.